# How to add a div on table with using jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery data table to manage tables. In this I need to add a div on table only not on the pagination div like below

```
<div class="class-name"> <table></table> </div> <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers"></div>
```

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: what output you expect?

Comment: The output as I shown in my question in which a div around table.

Comment: Can you not just add `class-name` to the table itself?

Comment: no this will not solve my purpose. I need to add a div around table.

Answer (score 7):

The question is old, but today I had the same problem. So here is the "official" solution:

In the JavaScript part where you initialize the DataTable, you can modify the generated DOM like this:

```
$('table').DataTable( {
    ...,
    dom: '<"class-name"t>p'
});
```

Where

- `<"class-name"` translates to `<div class="class-name">`
- `t` is replaced with the table (`<table>...</table>`)
- `>`closes the div as `</div>`
- `p` renders the pagination elements

The DataTables documentation explains the available options:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use wrap function:

```
$('table').wrap('<div class="class-name"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your table have a unique ID or class? Because then, you could simply use the jQuery function [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)().

Comment: I can wrap the table in a div using this but then datatable is not working on that table.

Comment: Pagination doesn't work, you mean? How about applying .datatable() first and then, in the callback, using wrap() to add your div? What's your final objective?